# Configure apache2 to have multiple authentication in the same browser

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, authentication

I added an authentication to my apache2, the problem I can't do 2 sign-in in the same browser, is that a way to do that without using a private window ?

Comment: SSL is not an authentication layer it's an encryption layer. So please define more clearly what "sign-in" mean.

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with Apache.  Browsers, usually share HTTP authentication, local storage, and cookie state between various tabs/windows.

HTTP authentication is based on the hostname and realm.  I suppose if you setup multiple DNS names for you site, you could get multiple logins.

About the only thing that permits this is some browsers permit a private/incognito Window which gives you a second login.

Comment: Somewhat related.  Describe HTTP authentication caching.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339244/using-apaches-mod-auth-across-multiple-sub-domains-for-single-sign-on